# What is the best approach to autonomously maintain a state of available workers

Tags: node.js, redis, architecture, load-balancing

Currently how my system is designed I spool up a 1-core instance that is only allowed one encoding job. This instance connects to redis and waits for a list of encoding jobs to be populated. The worker then pops the job from the list and sets itself to busy while the job is being ran, as soon as the job is done- it continues looking for more unfinished jobs.

My example worker.js

```
module.exports = function (redisClient) {
  const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
  var busy = false;
  function startCoStream(job) {
    console.log(job);
    busy = true;
    var proc = spawn('./costream.sh', [job.streamKey, job.leftIngest, job.leftKey, job.rightIngest, job.rightKey]);
    proc.on('exit', function (code, signal) {
      busy = false;
      readJobBus();
    });
    proc.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');
    proc.stderr.on('data', (chunk) => { 
      console.log(chunk);
    });
  }
  function readJobBus () {
    if (busy) return;
    redisClient.lpop('jobbus', function(err, reply) {
      if (!reply && !err) {
        setTimeout(readJobBus, 1000);
      }
      else {
        var job = JSON.parse(reply);
        if (job.type==0) {
          startCoStream(job);
        }
      }
    });
  }
  readJobBus();
  return redisClient;
}
```

This runs great in my current setup, the only problem is I need to know ahead of time the amount of encoding processes that are anticipated and provision the instances manually. My question is this, what is the best way of keeping this system autonomous and loosely coupled while maintaining a list of busy and available workers in order for me to implement auto-scaling.

Idea 1) Register the worker on a available worker list upon start, then remove from list upon the starting of the process and adding back once the process is done.
Problem 1) What if the worker dies while still on the available list, then the list would show 1 more available worker then the real state of the application.

What would be a good approach to this? The desired outcome is simple. When a worker is provisioned it connects to redis and places itself on a worker list, when the worker list has more then half the workers as busy, then provision more workers. What would be the best way to maintain this list without a dedicated system maintaining the list.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is, of course, to have a supervisor node which evaluates this.  Failing that, you will have to distribute that role to your worker nodes.  I would suggest that you have each idle node which is waiting for work check the worker list and test to see if more workers need to be provisioned.

This is tricky as you will have to have a distributed lock to keep multiple workers from picking up this task simultaneously.

1. Attempt to acquire supervisor lock, if blocked, goto #4
2. check number of busy workers, and provision more if necessary
3. release supervisor lock
4. look for work